# Forcing digital LOW

Tags: digital-logic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzScvs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above schematic is of a digital chip using 5v logic.  This chip is soldered directly to a board which is supplying the power and the chip can't be removed, or permanently altered.  The Input1 pin is driven by the board and is usually HIGH since it is connected to the 5V Power supply.  However, I would like to somehow drop the voltage down enough to have the chip read it as a logical LOW (without cutting the lead)

Would putting a load between input 1 and ground e.g. Lightbulb accomplish this?  Alternatively, could I short INPUT1 and GND to accomplish this?

I'm still rather new to electronics, so please bear with me...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without inserting a resistor in line with input 1, all you will achieve by shorting that line to ground is shorting the 5V power supply. The black lines in the circuit are regarded as zero ohms schematically and therefore what you do to the input line you also do to the 5V power line.

Answer (score 0):

"Would putting a load between input 1 and ground e.g. Lightbulb accomplish this?"

Yep! I believe it should. As it would act as a voltage divider that would lower the voltage read by input 1 for whatever it's cut-off is to register as "LOW". Though you would have to also put in a resistor in series with either to the right of your stated load or the left. It depends on how you would want to implement your voltage divider.

Shorting it would just short the 5v as stated by Andy.